# How does browser parses Reactstrap components to html tags?

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

We have a reactstrap component `Modal` which appears as a dialog box. If we actually inspect this element in the DOM, it is nothing but a `div` with a class name `modal-dialog.` Who actually converts this `Modal` to a `div`? Browser? Reactstrap?

Answer (score 0):

Reactstrap defines the `Modal` component as a `div`. See the source [here](https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/blob/1e21a2825ae46139a01a09c0242ef21adc308be0/src/Modal.js#L399).

When React renders this component, it results in the `div` you are seeing in the dev tools.